# Making an input that adds to a list

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to make an input text and a button when pressed will add to a ul list but I keep having this error in the console and I don't know why

> Uncaught TypeError: btn.addEventListener is not a function at script.js:5

Code :

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
var list = document.querySelector('.list');
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('add');

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var content = document.createElement('li')
    content.innerText = text.value
    list.append(content)
})
```

Comment: Provide your HTML code also.

Comment: I believe the method `getElementsByClassName` will return an array that's why you are encountering that error.

Comment: [`getElementsByClassName` returns a live HTML collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). You can't add an event listener to a list of things.

Comment: Use `querySelector/querySelectorAll` instead

Comment: Use `btn[0].addEventListener` because `getElementsByClassName` returns collection, not a single element you can add event to.

Comment: add [0] after `btn` like this `btn[0].addEventListener` and everything will work

Comment: yup after using querySelector it is fixed but the list item is undefined

Comment: [It works fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/y47krgn2/)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of all elements having the given class. To solve this error you have two options:

1. Make `add` id instead of class and use `getElementById` to get that element.

   `var btn = document.getElementById('add');`
2. If you do not want to make `add` id, we know `getElementsByClassName` returns an array you can access the elements inside this array by its index.

   `var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('add')[0];`
   In this case, keep in mind that the button you are trying to access with `add` class should be the first element with this classname.